# card columns not working side by side in firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

working on dynamic cards to display information. But I am fighting with firefox... Can't get it displaying the cards side-by-side.

http://codepen.io/n00n/pen/bBZKwb

Any idea whats my fail?

HTML

```
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/cards.css">


        <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Angular Material Library -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /**
             * You must include the dependency on 'ngMaterial'
             */
            angular.module('EspanioApp', ['ngMaterial']);


        </script>

    </head>

    <body ng-app="EspanioApp" layout="row" flex>

        <div layout="column" flex>

            <div layout="row" id="PageHeader">
                <div id="TopLogo">das Logo fehlt</div>
                <div id="TopNavigation">das Menü fehlt</div>
            </div>



            <!-- https://mikethedj4.github.io/Webkit-Scrollbar-Generator/ -->
            <div layout="row" id="PageContent" flex>

                <div layout="column" id="CardColumn" flex>

                    <div id="wrapper">

                        <div id="columns">

                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div layout="row" id="PageBottom">
                <div id="BottomInformation">das Impressum </div>
                <div id="BottomNavigation">das untere Menü fehlt</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body#index{
    background-image: url("../assets/start-page.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.body-row{
    display: table-row;
}

.body-cell{
    display: table-cell;
}

#TopLogo, #TopNavigation, #BottomInformation, #BottomNavigation{
    color: #F1BF00;
}

#TopLogo{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}

#TopNavigation{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}

#PageHeader, #PageBottom{
    position: relative;
    background: #AA151B;
    height: 175px;
}


#PageBottom{
    position: relative;
}

#BottomInformation{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    height: 175px;
    line-height: 175px;
}

#BottomNavigation{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 10px;
}

#PageContent {
    background: #F1BF00;
}

#CardColumn{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#PageContent .body-cell{
    padding: 10px;
}

.rightAlign{
    text-align: right;
}

a{
    color: #FFFF00;
    margin: 5px;
}

#contentframe{

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    body#index{
        background-image: url("../assets/start-page-smart.jpg");
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}

#wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    min-width: 800px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 15px;
    column-fill: auto;
}

.pin {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    margin: 0 2px 15px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

.pin img {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.pin p {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1920px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 7;
        -moz-column-count: 7;
        column-count: 7;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 2200px;
        min-width: 1600px;
        margin: 50px auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: why cannot you post any code here ?

Comment: other where complaining that I should better use code pen.. ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use change the property

```
-moz-column-fill: auto
```

to

```
-moz-column-fill: balance
```

Read about the column-fill here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-fill

It says.

**auto**

Is a keyword indicating that columns are filled sequentially.

**balance**

Is a keyword indicating that content is equally divided between columns.

```
#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: balance;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 15px;
    column-fill: auto;
}
```

P.S : if you wonder from where -moz came up its the vendor prefix which you need to use since you are checking it in firefox.